# How to add two Google Place Autocomplete search boxes in one page?

Tags: php, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add two Google Maps Autocomplete search boxes in one html page. However, the moment I copy the same code with same API only one of them works.

```
<body>
    <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
      <div id="pac-container">
        <input id="pac-input" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter a location">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>


<script>
  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });
    var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
    var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
    // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
    // bounds option in the request.
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
    autocomplete.setFields(
        ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
      }

      // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);

      var address = '';
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
      }

      infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
      infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
      infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener(id, types) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        autocomplete.setTypes(types);
      });
    }

    setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
    setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

    document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
        .addEventListener('click', function() {
          console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
          autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
        });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My API KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked all possible questions in stack with respect to this topic and none of them used an API key which was the main reason for me posting this question. I ran all those codes that I found online but none worked perfectly.

**To those who have the same problem as me, Here's the solution..**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Maps API v3 Multiple Autocomplete Inputs</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/lib/dummy.js"

  ></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Your API Code &amp;libraries=places"></script>

  <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">
      .autocomplete {
    width:300px;
}
  </style>


  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->

  <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

    var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {

function initialize() {

    var acInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete");

    for (var i = 0; i < acInputs.length; i++) {

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(acInputs[i]);
        autocomplete.inputId = acInputs[i].id;

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = 'You used input with id ' + this.inputId;
        });
    }
}

initialize();

    }

var alreadyrunflag = 0;

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        alreadyrunflag=1; 
        VanillaRunOnDomReady();
    }, false);
else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>');
    var contentloadtag = document.getElementById("contentloadtag")
    contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (this.readyState=="complete"){
            alreadyrunflag=1;
            VanillaRunOnDomReady();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout("if (!alreadyrunflag){VanillaRunOnDomReady}", 0);
}

  //]]></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input class="autocomplete" id="ac1" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text">
<br />
<br />
<input class="autocomplete" id="ac2" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text">
<br />
<br />
<input class="autocomplete" id="ac3" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text">
<br />
<br />
<span id="log"></span>


  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "42usv81j"
      }], "*")
    }

    // always overwrite window.name, in case users try to set it manually
    window.name = "result"
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```